# How to run mocha in the same file with the JS script

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

Is it possible to have the JS code and the mocha tests in the same file? The purpose will be to have both the implementation and the tests in the same file when you just want to play with something, learn JS, prepare for an interview, etc.

The file will be executed in VSCode using Debug (F5).

```
function increment(n) {
return n + 1;
}

mocha.setup("bdd");
const { assert } = chai;

describe('Array', function () {
    describe('#indexOf()', function () {
        it('should increment', function () {
            assert.equal(increment(1), 2);
        });
    });
});

mocha.run();
```

Trying to run this example which is how you run mocha tests in browser, I get an error "mocha is not defined"

I ran "npm install --save-dev mocha" and "npm install --save-dev chai".
The file is test1.js.
In app.js I have "require("./test1")".
The launch configuration is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
            "request": "launch",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "pwa-node"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does your example run? mocha tests are JavaScript so I don't see why you can also define the code to be tested in the same file.

Comment: It doesn't run, I get an error saying "mocha is not defined". I would like to have something like that, the example is how we run mocha tests in browser.

Comment: Have you set up mocha? Is this code inside a spec/test file?

Comment: I updated the question, please take a look

Comment: How do you run the test?

Comment: F5 will run the app.js which in turn will execute "require("./test1")" which will execute test1.js. In test1.js mocha.run() should launch the tests.

Comment: Mocha tests must be run using the mocha command. Have you read [their documentation](https://mochajs.org/)?

Comment: I did, but I was hoping that if you can mocha.setup and mocha.run in browser you can do that in node as well. As you said, is JS so you should be able to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more googling I found the solution, your Debug launch.json file have to have the below configuration. Basically the program you need to launch is "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha".

You do not need any mocha commands in your JS file: mocha.setup("bdd"); mocha.run();

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mocha Tests",
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": [
                "-u",
                "bdd",
                "--timeout",
                "999999",
                "--colors",
                "${workspaceFolder}/thon-ly-40-questions"
            ],
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```